Shopping cart deletetion bug
i tried to delete the last item from the cart. For all the previous item, the @GetMapping("remove-song-from-cart") work and return me to the cart page again but when hit the delete button of the last item. The method was not called. I think the problem is from the the get method remove-song-from-cart
 package musicstore.musicselling.Entity;
    
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
    
    import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
    import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
    import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
    import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
    import jakarta.persistence.Id;
    import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
    
    @Entity
    public class Cart {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long cartId;
    
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
        private Set<CartItem> cartItems = new HashSet<>();
    
        public Long getCartId() {
            return cartId;
        }
    
        public Set<CartItem> getCartItems() {
            return cartItems;
        }
    
        public void setCartItems(Set<CartItem> cartItems) {
            this.cartItems = cartItems;
        }
    
        public void addCartItems(CartItem item) {
            cartItems.add(item);
            item.setCart(this);
        }
    
        public void removeCartItems(CartItem item) {
            cartItems.remove(item);
            item.setCart(null);
        }
    
    }








    package musicstore.musicselling.Entity;
    
    import jakarta.annotation.Generated;
    import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
    import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
    import jakarta.persistence.Id;
    import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
    
    @Entity
    public class CartItem {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long itemId;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "cartId")
        private Cart cart;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "songId")
        private Song song;
    
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "albumId")
        private Album album;
    
        public CartItem() {
        }
    
        public Long getItemId() {
            return itemId;
        }
    
        public Song getSong() {
            return song;
        }
    
        public void setSong(Song song) {
            this.song = song;
        }
    
        public Album getAlbum() {
            return album;
        }
    
        public void setAlbum(Album album) {
            this.album = album;
        }
    
        public Cart getCart() {
            return cart;
        }
    
        public void setCart(Cart cart) {
            this.cart = cart;
        }
    
    }







package musicstore.musicselling.Controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import musicstore.musicselling.Entity.*;
import musicstore.musicselling.Repository.AlbumRepository;
import musicstore.musicselling.Repository.CartItemRepository;
import musicstore.musicselling.Repository.CartRepository;
import musicstore.musicselling.Repository.SongRepository;

    @Controller
    public class CartController {
        @Autowired
        SongRepository songRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        AlbumRepository albumRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        CartRepository cartRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        private CartItemRepository cartItemRepository;
    
        private Cart getOrCreateCart() {
            if (cartRepository.findByCartId(1L) == null) {
                Cart cart = new Cart();
                return cartRepository.save(cart);
            }
            return cartRepository.findByCartId(1L);
    
        }
    
        // add the song to the cart
        @GetMapping("/add-song-to-cart")
        public String addSongToCart(@RequestParam Long songId) {
            Cart cart = getOrCreateCart();
            Song song = songRepository.findBySongId(songId);
            CartItem item = new CartItem();
            item.setSong(song);
            cart.addCartItems(item);
            cartRepository.save(cart);
            System.out.println("Add success");
    
            return "redirect:/song-list";
        }
    
        // push the data of cart list to the cart page
        @GetMapping("/cart")
        public String songCart(Model model) {
            Cart cart = getOrCreateCart();
            double price = 0;
            List<Song> songItems = new ArrayList<>();
            for (CartItem cartItem : cart.getCartItems()) {
                if (cartItem.getSong() != null) {
                    songItems.add(cartItem.getSong());
                    price = price + cartItem.getSong().getSongPrice();
                }
            }
    
            String totalPrice = String.format("%.2f", price);
            model.addAttribute("totalPrice", totalPrice);
            model.addAttribute("songItems", songItems);
            System.out.println("cart item size: " + cart.getCartItems().size());
            for (CartItem cartItem : cart.getCartItems()) {
                System.out.println("Song id: " + cartItem.getSong().getSongId());
            }
    
            return "cart";
        }
    
        // remove the song from cart
        @GetMapping("remove-song-from-cart")
        public String removeSongFromCart(@RequestParam Long songId) {
            Cart cart = getOrCreateCart();
            Set<CartItem> cartList = cart.getCartItems();
            System.out.println("The fucking cart size: " + cartList.size());
            CartItem itemToRemove = null;
    
            for (CartItem item : cartList) {
                if (item.getSong().getSongId().equals(songId)) {
                    itemToRemove = item;
    
                }
            }
            if (itemToRemove != null) {
                cart.removeCartItems(itemToRemove);
                cartRepository.save(cart);
    
            }
    
            System.out.println("item to remove: " +
                    itemToRemove.getSong().getSongName());
    
            return "redirect:/cart";
    
        }
    
    }


when "The method was not called" does the console log have "The fucking cart size:"? could you doubly check whether the request is sent (see browser network tab)? so we can be sure its backend issue not front end one.

For the first 2 items in the cart, "The fucking cart size:" was shown in the console. I'm pretty sure that the front is fine.

the easiest suspect would be item.getSong().getSongId().equals(songId) but, we can't be sure until we check the parameter sent by frontend and the stuffs in the database.

The possible solution could be
if (itemToRemove != null) {
 cart.getCartItems().remove(itemToRemove); 
 cartRepository.save(cart);
}

because may be your database may not be synchronised,So directly fetching from database then deleting may work.
